# Neural Networks & ML without GPU. what are my options?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch

I am starting working with Neural Networks, ML etc. I don't have a GPU, what are my options?

Are Pytorch and Tensorflow good options? If so, which are the pros and cons of each, and which should I choose?

I will be using Python and Linux (ubuntu 20.04) if that makes any difference.

(I cant afford a GPU or cloud services because im broke and 15 y.o.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do. If you are working on images, you will need GPU. If you are working on other type of data, with classification or regression, you can use your CPU.

Working on Ubuntu is perfect, it is my choice too.

Now for Neural Networks, Tensorflow and Pytorch ARE the options, you may try any of them. I worked mostly on Tensorflow.

If you want to use GPU, you may try the Kaggle competitions where you may have a good amount of GPU every week. You may aslo try Google Colab notebooks, where you may have an amount of GPU, you have to connect with a Google account and eventually connect your notebook to your drive, where you can stock your data.

Comment: ok thanks! i will look into Kaggle but I dont think I will really need GPU (not yet anyway) my main goal for now is a crypto trading algorithm. thanks again for your help!

Comment: Try also Google Colab notebooks if you need GPU.

Comment: I would also add that for learning the basics, use small datasets like CIFAR10, since they are easier to train with a CPU.  "Big data" will give you headaches, hence why you might want to look at options like Kaggle and Colab.

Comment: And be careful to stop your GPU session when your program is finished, it is not done automatically and you will loose your GPU hours.